# rails helper nested content_tag with span inside link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionviewhelper

Hi i have tried almost everything and cant get this to work. The `title.capitalize` part doesnt get displayed. I tried using "+" but then i get error about expecting end keyword

```
def mailbox_section(title, current_box, opts = {})
  content_tag :li, opts do 
    link_to(conversations_path(box: title.downcase), html_opts = {}) do
      title.capitalize
      content_tag :span, :class => "badge" do  
        "2" 
      end
    end
  end     
end
```

Does anyone have a idea how to solve this ?

Comment: A Ruby block returns the value of the last line in that block. In this case, `title.capitalize` isn't the last line so its value isn't returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Ed based on it i was able to do this

```
def mailbox_section(title, current_box, opts = {})
  content_tag :li, opts do 
    link_to(conversations_path(box: title.downcase), html_opts = {}) do
  "#{title.capitalize} #{content_tag :span, :class => 'badge' do '2' end}".html_safe
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps string interpolation to get both parts into the link text string? Switched to single quotes and curly braces on the block for clarity in the nested usage.

```
def mailbox_section(title, current_box, opts = {})
  content_tag :li, opts do 
    link_to(conversations_path(box: title.downcase), html_opts = {}) do
      "#{title.capitalize} #{ content_tag :span, :class => 'badge' {'2'} }" 
    end
  end     
end
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting tSTRING_DEND ..._tag :span, :class => 'badge' {'2'} }" ... ^